# Problem with Bitnami Gitlab

Tags: git

I have installed Bitnami Gitlab on a centos 6.5, but I just see the error written below while trying to push to another project:

> ~/sample$ git push -u origin master
>
> git@-'s password: fatal: 'mahdi/sample.git' does not appear.
>
> to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>
> exists

Do you have any ideas on it?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?